# C# Using Generics and Delegates in a Factory Pattern

Tags: c#, delegates, factory

I am trying to create a factory where I can return a class type based on the type of class being passed into the factory.  Based on the result of that, I am then calling a method on the returned class with a related but separate signature.  I'm trying to use a delegate for the method signature, but I'm getting compilation errors.  See the following code snippets:

Policies:

```
public interface IPolicy
{
       
        Guid Id { get; }

        TypeEnum NetworkType { get; }

}

public class PPOPolicy : IPolicy
{
  // PPO specific properties...
}

public class HMOPolicy : IPolicy
{
  // HMO specific properties...
}
```

Calculators, that require a specific IPolicy derived type:

```
public static class PpoCalculator
{
  public static bool TryBuildEstimate(Treatment treatment, PPOPolicy policy,
            out InsurancePolicyEstimate estimate
        )
        {
         // implementation...
        }
}

public static class HmoCalculator
{
  public static bool TryBuildEstimate(Treatment treatment, HMOPolicy policy,
            out InsurancePolicyEstimate estimate
        )
        {
         // implementation...
        }
}
```

Calling code:

```
public static class BenefitEstimator
{
public static IEnumerable<InsurancePolicyEstimate> EstimateBenefit(Treatment treatment,
          IReadOnlyList<IPolicy> policies
        )
        {
         var primaryPolicy = policies.First();
         var calculated = Calculate(primaryPolicy, treatment, out var primaryEstimate);
        }

        private static bool Calculate(IPolicy policy, Treatment treatment, out InsurancePolicyEstimate estimate)
        {
            switch (policy)
            {
                case PPOPolicy ppoPolicy:
                    return CalculatorFactory.GetCalculator(ppoPolicy).Invoke(treatment, ppoPolicy, out estimate);
                case HMOPolicy hmoPolicy:
                    return CalculatorFactory.GetCalculator(hmoPolicy).Invoke(treatment, hmoPolicy, out estimate);
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(policy));
            }
        
}
```

This is the factory:

```
 public static class CalculatorFactory
    {
        public static TryBuildEstimate GetCalculator(IPolicy policy)
        {
            switch (policy)
            {
                case TreatmentInsurancePolicy treatmentInsurancePolicy:
                    return PpoCalculator.TryBuildEstimate;
                case DhmoInsurancePolicy dhmoInsurancePolicy:
                    return HmoCalculator.TryBuildEstimate;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my delegate:

```
public delegate bool TryBuildEstimate(Treatment treatment, IPolicy policy, out InsurancePolicyEstimate estimate);
```

I've tried making the delegate a generic like `TryBuildEstimate<in T>(Treatment treatment, T policy, out InsurancePolicyEstimate estimate) where T : IPolicy` but then the signatures don't match those in the calculator.

Is there a way to make this work, or a way to better structure this entire scenario? I'm ultimately trying to have an Estimator class that can get any type of calculator based on the Type of policy, and have it return the bool/out estimate signature.

Comment: I believe your approach is much more complicated than it needs to be. Why the delegate, if anything a callback function would be better but I don't think that's the solution either. If all you want to do is choose and instantiate a calculator type based on the estimator type then the Strategy pattern, with  factory may be the way to go. . . https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @quaabaam.  I looked at the strategy pattern and I still had trouble getting it to work the way I intend.  What I've done for now is to have the `BenefitEstimator.Calculate()` method use a switch statement to call the calculators directly, instead of using the factory.